# Each request takes longer than the last one

Tags: go, goroutine, go-http, waitgroup

I am scanning IP addresses in a network (where I am VPN'ed).

```golang
func scanTestHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var ipRanges ScanApiBody
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body)

    if err := decoder.Decode(&ipRanges); err != nil {
        http.Error(c.Writer, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    if len(ipRanges.Ranges) == 0 {
        http.Error(c.Writer, "No Ranges Provided", http.StatusBadRequest)
        c.Writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &digest.Transport{
            Username: "root",
            Password: "root",
        },
        // Timeout: time.Second * 3,
    }

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    ctx := context.TODO()
    count := atomic.Int32{}
    sem := semaphore.NewWeighted(200)

    streamChan := make(chan ScanApiRes)

    for ri := 0; ri < len(ipRanges.Ranges); ri++ {
        ipRange := ipRanges.Ranges[ri]
        for ip := ipRange.Start; !ip.Equal(ipRange.End); ip = incrementIP(ip) {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(client *http.Client, ip net.IP) {
                s := time.Now()
                sem.Acquire(ctx, 1)
                defer wg.Done()
                defer sem.Release(1)
                defer count.Add(1)

                _, err := client.Head(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s", ip))
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                }

                scannedIp := ScanApiRes{
                    // TODO: Add result of scan
                }
                streamChan <- scannedIp
                fmt.Printf("%v - %v - %v\n", count.Load(), ip.String(), time.Since(s))
            }(client, ip)
        }
    }
    go func(s chan ScanApiRes) {
        for item := range s {
            c.SSEvent("ip-summary", item)
        }
    }(streamChan)
    wg.Wait()
    close(streamChan)
}
```

Here are some of the logs from the terminal:

```
0 - 10.0.108.72 - 3.354931667s
1 - 10.0.108.16 - 3.678023666s
2 - 10.0.108.26 - 3.697749125s
3 - 10.0.108.14 - 3.736625542s
4 - 10.0.108.17 - 3.76629875s
5 - 10.0.108.4 - 3.823524458s
6 - 10.0.108.49 - 3.917469042s
7 - 10.0.108.18 - 3.969688917s
8 - 10.0.108.27 - 4.032998625s
9 - 10.0.108.37 - 4.069573833s
10 - 10.0.108.58 - 4.115886208s
11 - 10.0.108.42 - 4.15664s
12 - 10.0.108.41 - 4.19622275s
13 - 10.0.108.50 - 4.239392625s
14 - 10.0.108.22 - 4.276969542s
15 - 10.0.108.28 - 4.325756625s
16 - 10.0.108.21 - 4.354717417s
17 - 10.0.108.19 - 4.45664575s
18 - 10.0.108.29 - 4.484881208s
19 - 10.0.108.5 - 4.540046708s
20 - 10.0.108.52 - 4.579810375s
21 - 10.0.108.59 - 4.636688625s
22 - 10.0.108.7 - 4.804590792s
23 - 10.0.108.62 - 4.836241334s
24 - 10.0.108.31 - 4.862378333s
25 - 10.0.108.40 - 4.899775084s
26 - 10.0.108.8 - 4.936755375s
27 - 10.0.108.39 - 4.987377584s
28 - 10.0.108.44 - 5.029282458s
29 - 10.0.108.56 - 5.09347775s
30 - 10.0.108.55 - 5.1229095s
31 - 10.0.108.74 - 5.165836625s
32 - 10.0.108.83 - 5.212342958s
33 - 10.0.108.75 - 5.268523208s
34 - 10.0.108.76 - 5.335620042s
35 - 10.0.108.78 - 5.355333334s
36 - 10.0.108.45 - 5.378485666s
37 - 10.0.108.87 - 5.401183541s
38 - 10.0.108.73 - 5.429159459s
39 - 10.0.108.54 - 5.455198292s
40 - 10.0.108.77 - 5.480277125s
41 - 10.0.108.69 - 5.50076225s
42 - 10.0.108.32 - 5.557850833s
43 - 10.0.108.82 - 5.576487791s
44 - 10.0.108.11 - 5.634108416s
45 - 10.0.108.10 - 5.65177525s
46 - 10.0.108.34 - 5.690411459s
47 - 10.0.108.9 - 5.720816042s
48 - 10.0.108.61 - 5.741371583s
49 - 10.0.108.63 - 5.768093042s
50 - 10.0.108.33 - 6.176018541s
51 - 10.0.108.90 - 6.22304675s
52 - 10.0.108.65 - 6.240586375s
53 - 10.0.108.68 - 6.270167292s
54 - 10.0.108.64 - 6.287038958s
55 - 10.0.108.66 - 6.3059385s
56 - 10.0.108.79 - 6.334709458s
57 - 10.0.108.23 - 6.369138542s
58 - 10.0.108.67 - 6.394803292s
59 - 10.0.108.96 - 6.419526375s
60 - 10.0.108.92 - 6.437589084s
61 - 10.0.108.91 - 6.457618167s
62 - 10.0.108.93 - 6.478853667s
63 - 10.0.108.20 - 6.486225291s
64 - 10.0.108.30 - 6.519222416s
65 - 10.0.108.53 - 6.552244542s
66 - 10.0.108.71 - 6.615237208s
67 - 10.0.108.95 - 6.647860792s
68 - 10.0.108.38 - 6.66335975s
69 - 10.0.108.80 - 6.685832833s
70 - 10.0.108.70 - 6.711968167s
71 - 10.0.108.81 - 6.744482041s
72 - 10.0.108.6 - 6.764567958s
73 - 10.0.108.84 - 6.784441542s
74 - 10.0.108.51 - 6.807673s
75 - 10.0.108.85 - 6.830097708s
76 - 10.0.108.1 - 8.726269333s
77 - 10.0.108.13 - 8.754624583s
78 - 10.0.108.2 - 8.784178666s
79 - 10.0.108.48 - 8.821517959s
80 - 10.0.108.36 - 8.851277584s
81 - 10.0.108.25 - 8.867614375s
82 - 10.0.108.47 - 8.911953125s
83 - 10.0.108.15 - 8.937707625s
84 - 10.0.108.35 - 8.957096667s
85 - 10.0.108.3 - 8.981076375s
86 - 10.0.108.46 - 9.015118666s
87 - 10.0.108.94 - 9.034539208s
88 - 10.0.108.86 - 9.041660666s
89 - 10.0.108.88 - 9.061379084s
90 - 10.0.108.89 - 9.073388041s
91 - 10.0.108.12 - 9.114054333s
92 - 10.0.108.57 - 10.213736708s
93 - 10.0.108.24 - 10.245989041s
94 - 10.0.108.60 - 11.855088958s
```

#### Why does the elapsed time increase from 2-3 sec to more than 10 sec at the end? Shouldn't all calls take 2-3 sec and the whole scan should be done by then?

- This is unlikely to be due to rate limitation or request throttling from the server because all 100 requests are going to 100 different *servers*.
- Running this script multiple times produces a different order of the logs which means that `10.0.108.60` could take much less time in the second run (or even more).
- Scanning 300 Ip addresses takes much more time (over 90 sec) for the last/longest IP.
- I have played around with the `Timeout` settings of the `client` as well and I have not been able to get desired results.

Comment: Why are you executing `s := time.Now()` before `sem.Acquire(ctx, 1)`? Do you really want your own rate limiting to be included in the elapsed time? If you do I would argue you should maintain two separate elapsed times to separate the rate limiting wait time from the time to query the server.

Comment: You are right. I thought it wouldn't make a difference since I am scanning for only 100 and the semaphore limit is for 200. In any case, I moved the `s := time.Now()` before the actual http call and the results are still the same.

Comment: I didn't expect changing the order to change the results. :-) I was simply pointing out that if your rate limiting was activated then it would affect the elapsed times in a manner you probably didn't want. And you did say "Scanning 300 Ip addresses" which is more than 200. I confess I don't understand your "where I am VPN'ed" parenthetical. Could the throttling be on your client system? I would print the start and end times to see if there is an obvious progression.

Comment: By VPN, all I mean is that I am connected to the data centre via a VPN. Otherwise I cannot make these calls. I don't think that is a cause tho. I had a prototype in JS which worked just fine but it took too long to scan as all API calls were being made sequentially. I decided to recreate it in Go as I wanted to make all API calls concurrently. It is working but it is still taking way too long. At this point, I am willing to try anything to figure out the cause.

Comment: By client system, do you mean from my end? If so, where should I print the start and end times?

Comment: Yes, in this scenario the client system is the system you are running your program on. Start by simply including the `s` value in your stats line. I've been a support engineer solving problems like this for four decades. In my experience being methodical in debugging the problem is almost always the most efficient way to find the root cause. Form a hypothesis -- even if you think it is likely false -- then perform an experiment to prove or disprove the hypothesis. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Also, in a case like this it is often useful to further simplify the problem by removing bits of code irrelevant to recreating the problem. Such as your semaphore to rate limit the number of in-flight requests. Sometimes you'll find that an assumption you made is incorrect when removing that code changes the behavior.

Comment: I got an idea from your comments and tried something. I removed the call to the IP address and replaced it with a call to `example.com`. I tried it with the VPN turned off and it took 1.7 to 1.9 sec. Then I tried it with the VPN on and it took 15-25 sec. This definitely explains the cause now. I am not sure if I can do anything about it tho. Any suggestions? For context, I am using Tailscale to connect to the data centre.

Comment: "Any suggestions?" Sure, run your program on a system inside the data center whose systems you are probing. A VPN is, pretty much by definition, going to add unpredictable delays by routing your data through lots of systems not necessarily close to either your system or the target systems. Thus adding tens, even hundreds, of milliseconds of latency.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this script at the data centre.